# I do not want instance materials but the original materials in asset

Tags: unity-game-engine, instance

I made a script that copy all materials from a gameobject to another. It 'a script that runs in the editor to press a button.

```
TargetComponents[j].gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material=ComponentsToAdd[i].gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
```

Is a Unity 5 script, but would be the same in unity 4, it makes little difference, like:

```
TargetComponents[j].gameObject.transform.render.materials=ComponentsToAdd[i].gameObject.transform.render.materials;
```

Works but the materials that I copied are not the same but are **instances**.
I would like to know how to tell him not to create instances but use their original materials in asset.

Is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Unity offers two ways to get at a renderer's materials:

The [`sharedMaterial`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html) property will return the original material asset. That's what you want, here.

The [`material`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) property will internally copy the shared material, assign it to the renderer, and returns the new copy. That's usually the "safe" thing to do, especially for less experienced developers who may not understand the distinction, but it's almost never the right move for editor scripting.

Renderers also expose [`materials`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) and [`sharedMaterials`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html) arrays, in case you have multiple materials on one object.

You probably already know this, but be careful editing the shared material, as it is shared between all renderers and assets which reference that material.